# Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(styles). using ng-packagr

Tags: angular, storybook

Im trying to build a library with storybook and I'm getting this error

> Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(styles).

here's my angular json file

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ci-components": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/ci-components",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/ci-components/src",
      "prefix": "ci",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/ci-components/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/ci-components/ng-package.json",
            "styles": [
              "projects/ci-components/src/scss/styles.scss"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/ci-components/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/ci-components/tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/ci-components/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/ci-components/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/ci-components/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-cli:build",
            "port": 6006
          }
        },
        "build-storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:build-storybook",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-cli:build"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ci-components"
}
```

i'm using storybook 6.4 with angular 13, I have this problem only on building time

Comment: Realise this is a little old, can you publish your package.json or ng-package.json? The vlaidation error is related to those, not angular.json. Also, what script are you running that gives the error?